# Can't connect apache running on Amazon EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

Today I got one instance in Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu 14. Through SSH( A Java SSH Client directly from my browser (Java required) ) I am able to login and able to install LAMP server. 
I also include Inbound rules in Security group. 
But when I am trying to load apache from browser I got "This site is configured to require an SSL (https) connection." this error.
While trying with https then got unable to connect.
I didn't under the issue.

I have added ICMP in the security group and ping is working from my local.
Could you please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured any site or you are using the default site? Posting your httpd.conf or site definition file would be very helpful. If I recall correctly, in Debian-based distros (like Ubuntu), the configuration files are located on `/etc/apache2`, `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (there are usually symlinks pointing to definition files on `sites-available`).

Comment: Thanks Oriol, I didn't configured any site, I am just trying default site. Even phpinfo is also not opening https://public DNS/phpinfo

Comment: I selected Ubuntu as operating system but I took another instance with Amazon Linux and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I selected Ubuntu as operating system but I took another instance with Amazon Linux and it is working now.